# When using location manager, in xcode/swift, to get a user's current location, I get a value of nil. Any suggestions?

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

***UPDATE: Now getting location data, and the print statement `print("\(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude)")` works. If I try to assign what is on the right side of the = to a label.text value, I get an error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value. ***
Still new to this whole Swift/Xcode thing. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm running the following code (only code relevant to the issue shown). When a user presses a button and selects get location, it is supposed to get their location. Instead, I'm getting nothing. The text in the locationManager never prints and I'm at a loss.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation
import MessageUI
import Photos
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager()
    var currentLocation: CLLocation?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let currentLocation = locations[0]
        print("\(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude)")
        issueLocation.text = "\(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude)" ***ERROR***
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("Error: \(error)")
    }
```

Stuff that doesn't matter, I hope, and more code

```
    // Attach a location
    @IBAction func attachLocation(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if issueLocation.text == nil {
            issueImage.isHidden = true
        }

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Location options", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        // Get location
        let locationAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Get location", style: .default) { (action) in
            self.displayLocation()

        }    

        // Add get location action to alert controller
        alertController.addAction(locationAction)

        // Remove location
        let eraseLocation = UIAlertAction(title: "Erase location", style: .default) { (action) in
            self.issueLocation.text == nil
            self.issueLocation.isHidden = true
        }

        // Add erase location to alert controller
        alertController.addAction(eraseLocation)

        // Cancel action
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (action) in
            // Do nothing
        }

        // Add cancel action to alert controller
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

        // Display alert message on screen
        self.present(alertController, animated: true) {
            // Code to handle user selection
        }
    }

    func displayLocation() {
        let status = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
        let noPermissionMessage = "It appears that LoCAL Information does not have access to your location. Click Settings -> LoCAL Information -> Location to allow access to your location."

        switch status {
        case .notDetermined:
            locationManager?.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        case .authorized, .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
            print("JJJJJ")
            print("KKKKK")
            issueLocation.isHidden = false
        case .denied, .restricted:
            self.troubleAlert(message: noPermissionMessage)
        @unknown default:
            self.troubleAlert(message: noPermissionMessage)
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`locationManager` is declared but not initialized

Replace

```
var locationManager: CLLocationManager?
```

with

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
```

and remove the question mark after each occurrence of `locationManager`

Comment: That got it to print out the code in the locationManager func. Any idea how to add this output to a label's text value? When i add a line after the print statement, it gives me a unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. I just added a line that says labelname.text = "\(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude)". Thanks.

Comment: You have to connect the label in Interface Builder. And you have to add a backslash in `"\(currentL...`. And delete `as CLLocation` and also the annotation. Both are pointless

Comment: Sorry but I must have not copied the \ to the comment. Deleted the ```as CLLocation```. What's the annotation you mentioned? I also have an @IBOutlet var for the UILabel. Did I need something else?

Comment: Annotation is `: CLLocation`. The compiler knows the type. No, to assign the value to the label is supposed to work

Comment: Removed the ``` : CLLocation```. Still getting the Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value but only when assigning it to a label.text and not when just printing it out.

Comment: Once again you *have to connect the outlet in Interface Builder*

Comment: I thought I had it connected when I did the ```@IBOutlet var issueLocation: UILabel!```. Do I have to some other kind of connection?

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm self taught and still not very good at this and I'm struggling badly. Thank you for your time so far and I'll figure out how to connect the labelname and UILabel, though I thought by control dragging from the label to the code would make this connection and I just misunderstood.

Comment: There are a few ways to connect an outlet.

Comment: I'm beginning to see that. I'm just struggling with finding how to connect them in the way you said. I got the inspector open and the the label and UILabel show as connected in the Outlets section, but I'm assuming that's not what you meant.

Comment: I've tried using another label in place of this one and it still gives the error. I change the text of this other label elsewhere in the project with no issue. Does this mean there might be something else wrong?

Comment: Meanwhile your subsequent issue is beyond the scope of the question. Please ask a new one.

Comment: Will do. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @JasonH Remember that `currentLocation` won't always have a value. There's a reason it's optional. It's `nil` until the first GPS update, and there might not even ever be one (imagine a person who's in airplane mode, or in a subway without cell/wi-fi/gps reception). You need to design around this.